# CSS positioned element leaves blank space

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this issue. I have a web where I want to put certain fixed positioned element (kind of alert box for users). Therefore I decided to position it as fixed and put in the bottom left corner of the web. I assumed that it does not matter where I put the piece of HTML code as it will be positioned anyway, so i put it right under opening body tag. Everything went well, box ended up where I wanted it to be, BUT it leaves a strip of blank space at the top of the web (where the HTML code is). Isn't positioned element supposed to take up no space? My logic seems to be wrong.

[Image](http://postimg.org/image/gsp9j24qh/) of the problem.

Box HTML:

```
<div class="users-alert-box">
 Some Text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.users-alert-box {
background: #fffcd2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 35px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888;
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
left: 30px;
padding: 10px 15px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
width:170px;
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide website link?

Comment: Are you sure it is the alert-box causing the problems? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: It's always better to post a 1000 words instead of just 1 picture. other wise your question would be to short and to the point. we wouldn't want that....

try  this -->     display:  none;

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot post whole code, it's backend ~10000 lines code mixxed with lots of messy PHP. Anyway. I already tried setting display to none. It hides the alert-box but actually leaves the blank space at the top.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided do not create a top space. Check the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/tpoj91u4/

The spacing will be due to the `margin` of any other element.

Comment: That's the weird thing, it created the space regardless of where I put the code.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be PHP related error. Thanks to everyone for your time!